# Density histogram for ordinal factor using ggplot2

Tags: r, ggplot2

I have a simple dataset that looks like this:

```
school       score     grade subject
Your school  83.27     1     English
All schools 113.60     6     English
```

grade is an ordinal factor with 9 levels, school is a factor with 2 levels.

```
'data.frame':   12762 obs. of  4 variables:
 $ school : Factor w/ 2 levels "Your school",..: 1 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 ...
 $ score  : num  83.3 113.6 109.2 117.4 100.3 ...
 $ grade  : Ord.factor w/ 9 levels "1"<"2"<"3"<"4"<..: 1 6 6 7 4 3 6 1 6 6 ...
 $ subject: chr  "English" "English" "English" "English" ...
```

I'd like to plot a facetted histogram with ggplot2 using the density function. If I try it without density I get this:

```
p <- ggplot(ss, aes(x=grade))
p <- p + geom_histogram() 
p <- p + facet_wrap(~school)
```

[image]

When I add the density to normalise the y-axis I get this:

```
p <- ggplot(ss, aes(x=grade))
p <- p + geom_histogram(aes(y=..density..)) 
p <- p + facet_wrap(~school)
```

[image]

What am I missing?

Comment: Could you provide a `str(ss)`?

Comment: 'data.frame': 12762 obs. of  4 variables:
 $ school : Factor w/ 2 levels "Your school",..: 1 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 ...
 $ score  : num  83.3 113.6 109.2 117.4 100.3 ...
 $ grade  : Ord.factor w/ 9 levels "1"<"2"<"3"<"4"<..: 1 6 6 7 4 3 6 1 6 6 ...
 $ subject: chr  "English" "English" "English" "English" ...

Comment: @Heroka It already is.

Comment: Consider converting your factor to numeric. This will be correct since it's ordered factor.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

R cannot calculate density on a factor, even ordered one. Your best bet would be to convert `grade` to numeric (using for example `as.numeric(as.character(x))`).

```
xy <- data.frame(school = sample(c("your", "all"), size = 100, replace = TRUE),
                   grade = sample(1:10, size = 100, replace = TRUE))
xy$grade.factor <- factor(xy$grade, ordered = TRUE)

library(ggplot2)

# doesn't work for factors
ggplot(xy, aes(x = grade.factor)) +
  theme_bw() +
  geom_histogram(aes(y = ..density..)) +
  facet_wrap(~ school)

# works for integers/numeric
ggplot(xy, aes(x = grade)) +
  theme_bw() +
  geom_histogram(aes(y = ..density..)) +
  facet_wrap(~ school)
```